# Counting bytes consumed by char streams

Tags: java, io, nio

I have a large text file (csv) on disk that I'm splitting into lines. Something like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
while ((line = reader .readLine()) != null) { 
   ...
}
```

What I want to do is compute the offset from the start of the file for every 1,000 lines say, so if in the future I want to read the 10,001th line, I can jump straight to offset X, then start iterating.

The file could be encoded in any way, so there is no strong relationship between bytes and chars.

Does anyone know of any "counting readers", or an alternative approach? I'm very happy to implement a Reader myself, but don't want to write a very complex class if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

When you need random access, `BufferedReader` is not suited. Instead, you need to look into `Channel` and its subclasses like `FileChannel` and so on.

Simple example of reading using a channel:

```
    RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile("data/nio-data.txt", "rw");
    FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();

    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);

    int bytesRead = inChannel.read(buf);
    while (bytesRead != -1) {

      System.out.println("Read " + bytesRead);
      buf.flip();

      while(buf.hasRemaining()){
          System.out.print((char) buf.get());
      }

      buf.clear();
      bytesRead = inChannel.read(buf);
    }
    aFile.close();
```

Source: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/channels.html

As for your question of reading from where you left off, `FileChannel` defines a method `read(ByteBuffer buf,int position)` where position is the position in bytes where yu want to read from.

Comment: Thanks - but how would I figure out what byte offset line 1,000 starts at?

Comment: @Kong If your lines are of equal length then that's good or else you will need to structure your file in a way that tells you how many bytes each line takes